# Is it possible for humans to attain the power to display Vishvaroopa (cosmic form)of their own through any Yoga , Mantra or Tantra Sadhana?

Tags: mantras, yoga, tantra, sadhana, vishwaroop

Is it possible for humans to attain the power to display a cosmic form through any particular Yoga, Tantra or Mantra sadhana?

What do different scriptures and philosophies say about it? It's preferable to have a multi-dimensional perspective (i.e. perspective of multiple schools) in the answer instead of a monolithic perspective of a single school.

Comment: You can control what others are able to see hear or even feel. This is possible through yoga. For example in shaktipath initiation, Siddha masters, even just with eye sight can control your nadis, chakras and take some of your karmas too. You are asking too much questions related to tantra - you should read Uttara Gita.

Comment: It would be better not to equate a jīva with Īśvara. Even though jīva and Īśvara are non-different due to them sharing the same cetana svabhāva, in Advaita. However, there's still a bheda b/w the two, at the vyāvahārika stara. Kṛṣṇa, being the avatāra of Īśvara can show Viśvasvarūpa.

Comment: @Bingming Question doesn't really talk about Krishna or equating Jiva with Isvara. I have seen many ppl say Puranas etc. Mention About even rishis etc. Being able to show cosmic forms through siddhis etc. I only asking if scripture actually mentions such things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage Dadhichi showed his Vishwaroopam to Lord Vishnu, through the oneness with Bhagawan Shiva.

Shiva Purana 2.2.39.:

> Dadhīca said:—
>
> 35. O long-armed one, cast-off this illusion. On consideration, this is only a sham appearance. O Viṣṇu, thousands of inscrutable things are known to me also.
> 36. **I shall give you a divine vision. You will see in me the entire universe including you, Brahmā and Rudra. You shall then be alert.**
>
> Brahmā said:—
>
> 37. **After saying so, the saintly son of Cyavana, of body fully infused with the brilliance of Śiva, showed the entire universe in his body.**
> 38. Remembering Śiva in his mind and laughing fearlessly, the intelligent Dadhīca, the most excellent of the devotees of Śiva spoke to Viṣṇu, the lord of Devas, thus.

Our body is a micro universe, what present outside in macro universe is also present in our body. One who conquers his own body, conquers the whole universe also.

Yoga Kundalini Upanishad.:

> 1:81.: **“The microcosm and the macrocosm are one and the same;** so also the Linga and Sutratman, Svabhava (substance) and form and the self-resplendent light and Chidatma”.
>
> 2:49 **“Then he sees the whole universe in his body as not being different from Atman. This path of the Urdhva-Kundalini (higher Kundalini), O chief of Kings, conquers the macrocosm”.**

Everything is present in Sushuma Naadi, through which Mata Kundalini Shakti passes from Mooladhara Chakra to Sahasrara Chakra. This Sushuma Naadi passes through out spinal cord.

In Uttara Gita, Lord Krishna said to Arjuna.:

> Uttara Gita 2:15-17.: **“The Sun, the Moon, and the other Devatas, the fourteen Lokas of Bhur, Bhuvar, etc., the ten directions,East, West, etc., the sacred places, the seven oceans,the Himalaya and other mountains, the seven Islands of Jambu, etc., the seven sacred rivers, Ganga, etc., the four Vedas, all the sacred philosophies, the sixteen vowels and twenty-four consonants,the Gayatri and other sacred Mantras, the eighteen Puranas and all the Upa-Puranas included, the three Gunas, Mahat itself, the root of the Jivas, the Jivas and their Atman, the ten breaths, the whole world, in fact, consisting of all these, exists in the Susumna”.**
>
> Uttara Gita 2:13.: **“Like the backbone of a Veena, or harp, the long tract of bone with many joints that stretches from the seat right up to the head of a human being is called the Meru-Danda (Spinal Cord). There is a minute aperture or hole that passes right through this Meru-Danda from the Muladhara to the head; it is through this hole that there passes a Nadi which the yogis called the Brahma-Nadi or Susumna”.**

When Mata Kundalini Shakti reaches from Mooladhara Chakra to Sahasrara Chakra after passing all 6 chakras and 3 granthis or knots, it gets united with Bhagawan Parashiva, the Yogi becomes Brahman himself. By performing pranayama and different mudras.

Yogashikha Upanishad.:

> 1:168.: **“For all those who have a body, their body is the temple of Shiva. It gives them siddhi (fulfillment of yogic goal viz. salvation)”.**

Varaha Upanishad.:

> 5:53.: **“The six Chakras beginning with Muladhara are said to be the seat of Sakti (Goddess). From the neck to the top of the head is said to be the seat of Sambhu (Shiva)”.**
>
> 5:54.: “To the Nadis, the body is the support (or vehicle); to Prana, the Nadis are the support; to Jiva, Prana is the dwelling place; to Hamsa, Jiva is the support”.
>
> 5:55.: **“To Sakti, Hamsa is the seat and the locomotive and fixed universe.** **Being without distraction and of a calm mind, one should practise Pranayama”.**
>
> 5:60.: “It is only through Kumbhaka that Kumbhaka should be firmly mastered. **Within it is Parama-Shiva.** That (Vayu) which is non-motionless should be shaken again through Kantha-Mudra (throat-posture)”.

Thus,

YogaKundalini Upanishad.:

> 1:74.: **“Kundalini assumes the eight forms of Prakriti (matter) and attains Shiva by encircling him and dissolves itself in Shiva”.**
>
> 1:86.: **“Then it pierces Rudragranthi, after that, (all) the six lotuses (or plexuses). Then Sakti is happy with Shiva in Sahasrara Kamala (1000 lotuses seat or pineal gland). This should be known as the highest Avastha (state) and it alone is the giver of final beatitude (Moksham)”.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..